# Webview control on windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am stuck with kind of a weird problem. And with my limited Windows Phone app development experience, I am not able to fix it. So here is the problem.

I have a webview control in my universal app. I am rendering custom HTML on it from the ViewModel. My custom HTML contains images too. When I render it on desktop, it works perfectly. Even if I re-size the screen the webview is able to dock itself accordingly an the text is visible.

Now when I open this in mobile emulator or mobile device, the rendered web page occupy a very small area and everything is unreadable. It is as if I am opening a full desktop website on a mobile. Is there any way to load this custom HTML as if it was a mobile web content. So that I don't have to zoom to read it. Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: In apps compiled for Windows 10, WebView uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content. Would you please try to use Microsoft Edge in the mobile emulator to open your custom HTML, and check if the same problem would happen?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you'll have to set the width / height via CSS with something like:

```
html,body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; }
#full-size{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden; /* or overflow:auto; if you want scrollbars */
}
```

Have you tried tinkering with the CSS at all?